# Saving data entered in extJS textbox

Tags: extjs, textbox

I have made textboxes in ExtJS through which I will be taking input for an ID and a  name. I want to use these values(ID and name) in some other classes. So, I want to save these values somewhere(preferably in a string) so that they can be used later.
Please can someone advise me on how to do that.

```
    function textBoxTab() {

         var simple = new Ext.FormPanel({
             labelWidth: 75,
             frame: true,
             title: 'TAB_DIM',
             bodyStyle: 'padding:5px 5px 0',
             width: 350,
             defaults: {
                 width: 230
             },
             defaultType: 'textfield',
             items: [{
                 xtype: 'textfield',
                 name: 'Module_id',
                 fieldLabel: 'Module_id',
                 allowBlank: false // requires a non-empty value
             }, {
                 xtype: 'textfield',
                 name: 'Module_desc',
                 fieldLabel: 'Module_desc',
                 allowBlank: false // requires a non-empty value
             }],
             buttons: [{
                 text: 'Cancel',
                 handler: function() {
                     this.up('form').getForm().reset();
                 }
             }, {
                 text: 'Submit',
                 handler: function() {
                     var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                     form.submit({
                         clientValidation: true,
                         url: 'save.txt',
                         success: function() {
                             Ext.Msg.alert('saved');

                         },
                         failure: function(form, action) {}
                     });
                     if (form.isValid()) {
                         //Ext.Msg.alert('Submitted Values', form.getValues(true));
                         this.up('form').getForm().submit();
                     }
                 }
             }]
         });

         simple.render(document.body);
     }
```

I have tried this "url:'save.txt" thing but it is not working.
Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to save values in text file

Comment: Do you want to use the values that you write in the textfield or just the name of the texfield? If it's the first case, use selectors, or use form.getValues() due to you are using a form panel.

Comment: @qmat I want to use the values that are entered in the textfield

Comment: @zan not exactly. I just want to save the values somewhere that can be used later. Even a string would do.

Comment: If you want those values, try this. (i assume that you are using ExtJS3):             simple.getForm().getValues() in your controller or in your code.

Comment: @qmat I am using ExtJS 4.1 . Will it still work?

Comment: Yes, it still work. Check this for more info: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-getValues

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to store them in a model, and have a controller manage your views and models. 
There is several guide on how to architect your ExtJS application using MVC (model-view-controller) :

- http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/application_architecture
- http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/mvc_pt1
- http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/mvc_pt2
- http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/mvc_pt3

(The previous links are for ExtJS v4)